# How to distinct key and calculator on Flink + Pulsar

Tags: scala, flink-streaming, apache-pulsar

I am a newbie, I am working on Flink and Pulsar.
I have a task about calculator distinct data from pulsar on SlidingProcessingTimeWindows of Flink

the my windowSize: 60s and windows slide : 5s

my data consumer from topic pulsar on every seconds (recieved 2 message/ 1 seconds) :

```
00: 
    - a.example.com 
    - a.example-2.com
---
01: 
    - b.example.com
    - a.example-2.com
---
02: 
    - c.example.com
    - a.example-2.com
---
03: 
    - a.example.com
    - a.example-2.com
---
04: 
    - b.example.com
    - a.example-2.com
```

How to group key and calculator to receive results:

```
example.com => 3
example-2.com => 1
```

I have taken much time for research about that, but I can not resolve it.

And I have a problem, when the first window slide run, my job received all data from this current time to the past, I only received data by the window size.

Answer (score 0):

Flink SQL is a good fit for this.

```sql
SELECT window_start, window_end, domain, COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE(
    HOP(TABLE Events, DESCRIPTOR(time), INTERVAL '5' SECONDS, INTERVAL '60' SECONDS))
  GROUP BY window_start, window_end, domain;
```

You can execute SQL directly from Scala via `TableEnvironment#executeSql` or you can use the [Table API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/tableapi/#slide-sliding-windows).

Comment: Thanks.
But your solution can not resolve my problem.
At here : 
We have sub-domains, we need to distinct by every sub-domain, and count them by root domain.
How to does it?